# How to prove this equation $E(|X|I\{|X|>K\})\rightarrow 0$ as $K\rightarrow \infty$, if $X$ is integrable?

Tags: measure-theory

Assume $X$ is integrable, i.e., $X\in L^1$.That is $E(|X|)<\infty$

How to prove this equation below?

Since $X$ is integrable, X is finite almost everywhere

$Y_k=|X|I\{|X|>K\}\rightarrow 0$ pointwisely as $K\rightarrow \infty$

Since $Y_k=|X|I\{|X|>K\}\leq |X|$,

according to Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have,
$\int Y_k dP \rightarrow \int 0 dP=0$

I can not make sure of this proof. Can anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: When you write $P(|X|I(|X| \geq  K))$, there you are completely off. I understand you want to try and apply Markov's inequality, but that won't happen here because you have an expectation of a random variable which is not in general an indicator. Thus you have a non-event and you are trying to take the probability, which makes no sense. So you need other tools. Do you know the dominated convergence theorem? (And the weaker monotone convergence theorem etc. ) because this is a standard application of such a theorem.

Comment: get it. I will make some change soon.

Comment: Fantastic. If your change is worth an answer, I will inform you.

Comment: One question: Why we use $X_n$

Comment: Mistake : I meant $|X|I_{|X| > K}$, where $K$ is changing. Sorry, I  will delete the comment. But nothing has changed, you still have the sequence on $K=1,2,...$ , for which you have to apply dominated convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess you mean $|X|I\{|X|>K\}$ a sequence of  random variables when K is changing

Comment: Correct, I have changed that.

Comment: I have already finished the  sufficient condition part. Let's make some changes.

Comment: All right, do so.

Comment: I just make some change. But still can not make sure. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This proof is fine, it seems!

Comment: Not entirely fine. We have almost sure convergence, not pointwise and the answer also mixes $k$ and $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of your proof is correct but written needlessly complicated.

In the following answer I assume that $X$ is real-valued (this is no restriction since $X$ is integrable and hence finite almost everywhere).

We have $Y_k:=|X|I_{\{|X|>k\}}\to 0$ pointwise (or almost everywhere if $X$ can take infinite values) and by dominated convergence ($|Y_k|\leq |X|$ for all $k$ and $X$ is integrable) we get
$$\mathbb{E}Y_k\to 0$$ and this is what you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already made some changes according to your suggestion.

Comment: Do you assume that $X$ is real valued? I.e. is $X$ a map $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$? Or is $X$ a map $\Omega \to [-\infty,+\infty]$.

Comment: In that case you have to change "pointwise" by "almost everywhere" on your answer. Indeed, note that $Y_k \to |X|I_{\{|X|=\infty\}}$ pointwise and this limit variable is $0$ almost everywhere since $X$ is finite almost everywhere (because $E|X|<\infty$). Moreover, in your answer you mix $k$ and $K$. Might want to fix that as well. Make these changes and I'll look again if it's correct.